# Kafka 0.9 on AWS Ec2 instance, Error when sending message to topic... Batch Expired

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am sending a simple hello message from the console producer to a kafka 0.9 broker on an Ec2 instance to it's internal ip address within a VPC.

The error I get is Batch Expired (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list kafka1.acme.local:9092 -topic misc-verify
hello from laptop
[2016-08-11 09:57:39,126] ERROR Error when sending message to topic misc-verify with key: null, value: 17 bytes with error: Batch Expired (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

Both machines are on the private network.  The server is otherwise accessible with ping, ssh, etc.

I have the same version Confluent installations on the producer machine (confluent-2.0.1)

The console producer on the broker server kafka1.acme.local works, messages are received as expected.  Only producers from other machines fail with the Batch Expired error.

The message is never received to the topic log on the broker server, kafka1.acme.local

I installed kafkacat and it looks like this (with 0.0.0.0 for the broker host)

```
> kafkacat -L -b kafka1.acme.local:9092
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: kafka1.acme.local:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 0 at 0.0.0.0:9092
 1 topics:
  topic "misc-verify" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 0, replicas: 0, isrs: 0

%3|1470930115.688|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-0| 0.0.0.0:9092/0: Failed to connect to broker at 0.0.0.0:9092: Undefined error: 0
%3|1470930115.688|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-0| 0.0.0.0:9092/0: Failed to connect to broker at 0.0.0.0:9092: Undefined error: 0
```

Settings from our kafka server.properties file on kafka1.acme.local (non-production server)

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
port=9092
host.name=10.10.1.74
#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000
log.retention.hours=168
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=kafka1.acme.local:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is usually a problem when Kafka is advertising a private address not reachable by clients. Check property advertised.listeners